# A riddle - In hope of a fertile land

Tags: riddle

> I defend myself from thieves
>   Here to steal my liquid gold
>   I reach up high towards the sky
>   In hope of a fertile land
>   I diet most of the year
>   Saving my food for when its needed

What am I?

Comment: No correct answers so far

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's a

> Cactus

I defend myself from thieves
Here to steal my liquid gold

> Cacti have thorns to protect the water they store. I guess water would be considered liquid gold in a desert.

I reach up high towards the sky
In hope of a fertile land

> Cacti grow in a desert

I diet most of the year
Saving my food for when it is needed

> Cacti definitely have to save the water they have for when it's needed since they're in a desert.

Comment: This was my theory as well, but never got around to fleshing it out.

Comment: Correct, well thought out

Answer (score 11):

Are you a

> Beehive

I defend myself from thieves

> Thanks to bees

Here to steal my liquid gold

> Honey

I reach up high towards the sky

> High up in trees sometimes

In hope of a fertile land

> Need flowers

I diet most of the year
Saving my food for when its needed

> I store honey

Comment: Im afraid not, nice idea though

Answer (score 7):

Could you be a

> Maple Tree

I defend myself from thieves
Here to steal my liquid gold

> Maple Trees have bark to protect their sap

I reach up high towards the sky
In hope of a fertile land

> Trees grow upward, looking for sunlight, their nourishment

I diet most of the year
Saving my food for when it is needed

> After dropping their leaves in autumn, their main source of energy is gone. They have no "food" source for the colder months, so trees depend on stored energy.

Comment: Is there any reason for specifically choosing "Maple" among possible trees?

Comment: I picked a tree that I know has sought-after sap and was not an evergreen. I wanted to be specific, and I'm no arborist, so my options were pretty limited.

Comment: I did not think of "evergreens"! I was only asking because reading the question immedialty made me think of trees too, and I didn't want to post the same answer as you (and even less now, since yours matches more).

Comment: I had a different vision about last clue though (I diet most of the year
Saving my food for when it is needed) : some trees only produce fruits during summer

Comment: Not quite, bit closer

Answer (score 1):

I had an idea even though I doubt it's the intended answer.

> Cryptocoryne genus of aquatic plants

I defend myself from thieves

Here to steal my liquid gold

> Aquatic plants have several ways of defending or out-competing other plants for light. Without light all plants will melt and die

I reach up high towards the sky

> Aquatic plants will shoot leaves up to ensure they get the sunlight that filters through the water. This is called the *aerial advantage* [Ecology of Planted Aquariums, Diana Walstad]

In hope of a fertile land

> Crypts are bulbous and flower. Without the light above and the nutrients below, it will not flourish. By outcompeting the surrounding plants for light, they will die and the nutrients will be left for the Crypt

I diet most of the year

> Plants cannot use photosynthesis when there is no sunlight. They also cannot use photosynthesis depending on what wavelengths of light are available at their depth. The time in which there is light that can be used is less than the time where there is not.

Saving my food for when its needed

> The production of photosynthesis is usually some sort of sugar or salt that can be utilized more efficiently when *other minerals and nutrients* are present. Free carbon is also produced by bacteria which is not constant. Carbon is usually the limiting factor in plant growth.

Comment: Very good I'm afraid not. It is a plant though

Comment: Probably a vine then.

Comment: Nope, sorry - here's a hint, don't take things literally

Answer (score 1):

> I think its a cloud, I don't know why though, it just feels right. It stays high in the sky, and stores water as food. It can protect itself from thieves that aren't necessarily people, but they could be.

Comment: Or a seed! But i dont really know, im usually really good at riddles.